# How to separate fields in command output with spaces?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

When I run `sockstat -l`, I get an output like this. If the usernames and command names are large, column 2 collides with column 3. I don't want that. I would like to separate these columns by a space whenever collision happens. How do I approach this?

Current Output:

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
xxxxxxxxxx apacheexp2356 3  tcp46  *:9117                 *:*
root     ntpd       819   20 udp6   *:123                 *:*
prometheus prometheus870  3  tcp46  *:9090                *:*
root     httpd      1049  3  tcp6   *:80                  *:*
```

Expected Output:

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
xxxxxxxxxx apacheexp 2356 3  tcp46  *:9117                 *:*
root     ntpd       819   20 udp6   *:123                 *:*
prometheus prometheus 870  3  tcp46  *:9090                *:*
root     httpd      1049  3  tcp6   *:80                  *:*
```

**Update1:**
Exceptional case where command has a number

Current Output with the solution provided:

```
USER COMMAND  PID FD PROTO LOCAL ADDRESS FOREIGN ADDRESS
nagios nrpe 3 2222 4 tcp6 *:5666 *:*
```

Expected output:

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
nagios   nrpe3      2222  4  tcp6   *:5666                *:*
```

Comment: Please post the expected output in your post in CODE TAGS.

Comment: This is not a bash issue, it is entirely a result of how sockstat generates output. If you want it to look different you'll have to modify it and compile your own version.

Comment: @Turn: thanks for the info. I am not experienced enough to do that. I am thinking of splitting the column 2 if it has alphabets and numbers. It may result in false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following may help you in same.

```
sockstat -l | awk '{match($2,/[a-zA-Z]+/);$2=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH) FS substr($2,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'
```

Or to differentiate between everything and digits following may help, considering that digits may come at last of the process name:

```
your_command | awk '{match($2,/[^[:digit:]]*/);$2=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH) FS substr($2,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
your_command | awk '{
match($2,/[a-zA-Z]+/);
$2=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH) FS substr($2,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1
'
```

Comment: thanks. there is one issue with this answer. if there is an underscore in the command name, it is being replaced by a space. For example, `apache_exp68269` is converted to `apache _exp68269`. I'll work on fixing it. thanks a lot

Comment: @pdna. I could fix it. So whichever process you want to separate as it will do for everything, let me know I could help you here more.

Comment: @pdna is there ever a chance of the *command* having numbers in the name? (e.g. like `dhcpd4` or `dhcpd6`)  That may throw a wrinkle into the mix.

Comment: yeah looks like there is. example nrpe3. i may have to do a character count. if column1+column2 = x characters, then collision happens

Comment: @pdna, David C. Rankin sir is right, if you could give possibilities then I could make  it as per that also(as I already mentioned in previous comment too).

Comment: @pdna, as I requested before, is there any special process only which you want to format? It may ease the things then here.

Comment: there could be many exceptional cases here. nrpe3 is one example. I am not aware of all the processes on machines. So apparently, if column1+space+column2 exceeds 20 characters, collision happens. So just add a space after 20th character if c1+c2 are large.

Comment: Your second answer would split `nagios nrpe3 2222` into `nagios nrpe 3 2222`, creating an additional column

Comment: @pdna, then please show us the sample input with conditions and possible expected output too in sample in CODE TAGS I will make the necessary changes in command then.

Comment: I updated the outputs. it looks like the logic has to be based on the character count unless you have better ideas.

Comment: @pdna, I would like to request you again, whichever processes then we need to leave or whichever processes we need to work on then, because your first Input was also having digits and alphabets?

Comment: Sorry if I am being vague, I am not trying to implement this for a special process. I looked at few machines and there are few exceptional cases where process has a number in the middle, like `a5b`. I think we got the logic wrong at the beginning.

Comment: @pdna, np. Please do let me know if I could help you in any other thing related to this, will be happy to help, enjoy learning cheers :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164024/discussion-between-pdna-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: With my GNU awk I have to attach the following to get a nice layout: `| sed 's/LOCAL ADDRESS/LOCAL_ADDRESS/;s/FOREIGN ADDRESS/FOREIGN_ADDRESS/' | column -t`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing 21st character with a space resolves the issue
`sed 's/./ /21'`. If there are any exceptional cases, please point out.